# How to prevent user login from multiple devices in Django REST?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a subscription based platform, where user buys a subscription plan and then he/she can get access to the content.

Tech Stack: React in Frontend and Django REST Framework in Backend

I want to find a way to prevent user login from multiple devices or multiple tabs from a browser. There should be one session per user.

I have researched about it but could not find anything suitable. Some are using session authentication scheme to store the user session and adding middlewares and prevent multiple logins.

But i am using JWT token Authentication scheme. I am storing JWT token in front end.

How should i implement in such case which not having session authentication? Any leads?

Comment: Store user agent of the device. Then in your API calls, check if the user agent has changes, if it is, then logout the user.

Comment: How do i logout from the front end ? I am not storing any session in the database. I am using stateless JWT Token Authentication

Comment: How about getting mac address of device using React and keep that mac address in Django database? Then every time user tries to login, then you can check his mac address.

Comment: This is an issue. I recommend you use a stateful token system. Logging out users before the token is expired is not possible with just JWT in place

Comment: Okay I'll work on it, still any other approach ?

Comment: any good approach on this topic?